Using COUNTIF with SUBSTITUTE
I have a column filled with data that all starts with a letter, and ends with a number. For example, values of first 5 cells are:




A




1
X: 1


2
Y: 5


3
X: 5


4
X: 150


5
Z: 20



I have figured out how to sum all the numbers with the letter "X".
=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("X: ";range));SUBSTITUTE(range;"X: ";"")+0))

Is it possible to count how many cells have values between 1 and 5, and that all start with the letter "X"?
I tried to apply similar logic but with no luck. I also tried to combine RIGHT() and LEN() functions to get the number values, but some cells in the array are empty, so I got #VALUE! error.

You need to apply another approach:
=SUM((LEFT(A1:A5;1)="X")*(VALUE(MID(A1:A5;4;10))<6))

or
=COUNT(1/(0+SUBSTITUTE(A1:A5;"X: ";"")<6))

This picture shows how the last formula works step by step:

And finally, COUNT counts numbers only ignoring errors.

If all values are of format "letter: number", these would work:
=LET(r; A1:A5; x; IFERROR(0 + SUBSTITUTE(r; "X: "; ""); 0); SUM(x))

=LET(r; A1:A5; x; IFERROR(0 + SUBSTITUTE(r; "X: "; ""); 0); SUM((x>=1) * (x<=5)))



Since per tag you are using MS365 then make use of TEXTAFTER() and then get the counts of the reciprocals:
=COUNT(1/(--TEXTAFTER(A2:A6,"X: ")<6))


